# Is there an industry standard output format for OCR?

Tags: standards, ocr

Is there an industry standard output format for OCR? I can't seem to find any thing that is defined as an industry standard, nor am I very experienced with OCR so I wouldn't know if there was a standard either.

Comment: No. [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) is a broad concept, a *means* - but to what end? Stylus input? Reading in from a USB pen-to-text? Converting a dead-tree book to PDF? Extracting simple plain-text? So, determine the *end*; within that there may be some "industry standards".

Comment: @user2246674 Business requirements. I need to use the standard if there is one; if not, then I'm to use to most widely used.

Comment: Well, what is a "business requirements"? What tool should be able to open/view the output? How is the information transferred to others? What sort of text input is allowed, and to what end? What about diagrams or mockups? Word is perfectly capable of being used for "business requirements"; wether or not it is the most suitable for a given purpose is another issues.

Comment: @user2246674 we have a custom system that will be reading the OCR output.

Comment: Okay .. and? Again, OCR is a *means*, and not the *end*. Is there an "industry standard" for the custom system? How does the system expect to get input? What does it expect to get? What does it do with the data it gets? None of these questions relate to OCR - what if the data came from *existing* data-sources and not human writing? Also to explore; what *output* does the chosen OCR library/tool produce? How can/should this output be consumed?

Comment: @user2246674 I'm currently investigating which OCR library/tool to use. Also, no offense, but I would appreciate just an answer to the question. I understand that you're trying to help. But I asked a very specific question because I wanted a specific answer.

Comment: The problem is there *is no specific answer* to the question *as* given. Actually, there is. It was in my first reply: *no.*

Comment: @user2246674 I really do appreciate your trying to help. I just don't want you to be wasting your time is all. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such one format, but there are commonly used practices and open-standard formats that will satisfy your requirements.  This question is like asking "what is the standard result from cooking potatoes".  Mashed potatoes, french fries, or baked (Not sure where that example came from, I must be getting hungry...)

Also, an "industry standard" will depend on the specific industry.  If you are in a specific vertical, then some formats will be more common (almost standard) than others.  For example:

- Medical - HL7 formatted text
- Libraries - ALTO PDF
- Legal/eDiscovery - PDF Text Under Image
- Integration/Automation - XML

In general, I will not be wrong if I answer your question that most commonly used and industry-accepted formats are: TXT, XML, PDF (several flavors).  Each has unique properties and specific uses, but each can be widely used by other technologies due to open standards.

Approaching it from the opposite end is better, meaning thinking through 'business requirements' what will happen with the data and where it needs to be absorbed should exactly define what hand-off format you would like to use from OCR output.

Comment: To answer the question of which specific industry: I work with digital preservation of historical documents, capture of legal documents of any kind (literally any kind: HR, invoices, real estate, medical, you name it). Basically, any industry you can think of that would use OCR, I'm involved.

Comment: I couldn't find your email on that page. I work for a non-profit organization that has business dealings in thousands of industries including the history of the organization itself...hence the preservation of historical documents.

Answer (score 2):

[hOCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOCR) is an open standard which defines a data format for representation of OCR output.

Answer (score 0):

XIEO (http://xieo.info) uses a (Maya Software) proprietary format called CML (Clix Markup Language) that efficiently encodes page, zone, line, text box, and related information.  VisualText/NLP++ (available at http://www.textanalysis.com) has a special tokenizer pass to "inhale" that format and produce a ready-made parse tree.  NLP++ analyzers can then build on that initial parse tree.

This work flow has been used for more than 5 years at XIEO, primarily for processing Official Records documents (deeds, mortgages, clerk of court, etc) and extracting information from them.

One can clean up the OCRed text, re-zone to fix up OCR errors and mis-zoning, and extract the pertinent information from text, in this workflow.

Amnon Meyers, CTO, Text Analysis International, Inc  amnon.meyers@textanalysis.com